# Backbone: Collection not being passed into view with Require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I'm rewriting a Backbone.js app trying to use an AMD approach.  I've downloaded the AMD-ified versions of Backbone and Underscore.  I checked and jQuery, Backbone and Underscore all get called.  It's a fairly simple project, but for some reason my collection is no longer being passed to my view.  I'm new to AMD.

Here is my model:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
    var tableModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    return tableModel;
});
```

Here is my collection:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/tableModel'
],
function($, _, Backbone, tableModel) {
    var tablesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: this.url,  // passed into collection at runtime, so same code can process multiple sets of data
        model: tableModel,
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            if (options && options.url) {
                this.url = options.url;
            }
            this.fetch({
                success: function(data, options) {
                    if ($.isEmptyObject(data.models)) {
                        App.Collections.Tables.NoData(data);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });

    return tablesCollection;
});
```

Here is my view:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/tableModel',
    'collections/tablesCollection',
    'views/tableView'
],
function($, _, Backbone, tableModel, tablesCollection, tableView) {
    var tv = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        initialize: function() {
            console.log(this.collection);  // returns collection and undefined 
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);  // errors: this.collection is undefined
        },
        render: function() {
            return this;
        }
    });

    return tv;
});
```

Here is where the view and collection are instantiated:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/tableModel',
    'collections/tablesCollection',
    'views/tablesView'
], function($, _, Backbone, tableModel, tablesCollection, tablesView) {
    var t = new tablesCollection(null, { url: 'main-contact'} );
    var tables = new tablesView({ collection: t, template: 'main-contact-template'});
    $('#web-leads').html(tables.render().el);

});
```

Why am I getting `function (){return c.apply(this,arguments)}` returned when I `console.log(tablesCollection)`?  It's like the collection is not being passed in.  Could it be a paths issue?  My project is structured with a `js` folder with subfolders called `collections`, `models` and `views`.  If I `console.log(this)`, I get:
[image]

My data is in there, but is this what I need?  Why do I not get my collection when I try to `console.log` it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `tablesCollection` directly. Use `this.collection`. You have already initialized view with it

Comment: If I `console.log(this.collection)`

Comment: What browser are you using? `console.log` acts a little weird in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the function tablesCollection, i.e. the Backbone.Collection.extend(...) function.

The *function* tablesCollection is probably passed in fine into the view. However, you need to instantiate the object, e.g. new tablesCollection(null, {url: 'url'}) before logging it to the console, otherwise the extend wrapper function will show, which is what you see now.

Comment: If I `console.log(tables)` that returns fine, but I still get `this.collection is undefined`.

Comment: Do you mean instantiate it in the view?